# How do you send emails at a specific time with an attachment (SMTP related)

Tags: c#

For example I have an attachment that is to be sent at exactly 3:00 pm everyday. No sql data base or anything. Im assuming I could leave visual studio open as the code would be running everyday until it hit 3:00 pm exactly, and then it sends the body of the email and the attachments and then the code stops because it has executed its daily task of the day. I know I have to use something alone the lines of date.time.now = 3:00 pm and then it sends but im not sure how to do an if statement based off of it
I was thinking of trying something along the lines of

```
if(today == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
attachments.add()...
}
```

And repeating it until it says Friday with copy and paste and that would do it daily technically but to set it to send at exactly 3:00 pm while visual studio is running the code and waiting until it hits 3:00pm for it to actually send the attachments and body of the email

```
try
{
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("ip", port))
    {
        client.EnableSsl = false; //always false
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        MailMessage msgObj = new MailMessage();
        msgObj.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("filedirectory")); 
        msgObj.IsBodyHtml = true; //always sets true, if the body contains html it turns text to html
               
        msgObj.To.Add(Destination); 
        msgObj.From = new MailAddress("somerandom@gmail.com"); 
        msgObj.Subject = YourMessageSubject; 
        msgObj.Body = messageBody2;  //html

        client.Send(msgObj); 
    }
}
catch (System.Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("somethings broken");
}
```

Comment: How about instead of trying to code scheduling into a program that you leave running in your debugger all the time you make a simple console application that does the thing just once, and you make a scheduled task that executes it?

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I would publish the visual studio code application, and then go to an application on the desktop called task scheduler, create task, go to trigger and set it up how often you want it to be sent, then go to action and press new and find the "setup.exe" with the published one you did earlier and then you are good to go. It only works for one time, daily, monthly, and what time it sends. I haven't figured out how to make it send say every 3 hours or something yet but its not needed since my actual goal was just to send it daily at a specific time.

Comment: Take a look at HangFire. But I do agree with @Logarr that it would be much simpler to create a Console application and schedule it as a Task. We used HangFire in the past and it did work for a while but when the application became more complex all kinds of problems with transaction biting each other cropped up. We then moved to a Console application. Much easier and less error prone.